# in io_uring, when I submit a new sqe, how to let a thread which is blocking on wait_cqe know there is a new sqe is submited and work complete

Tags: linux, asynchronous

at first, create a thread to run `wait_cqe`, it will be blocked because there is no `sqe` done.
then I create another thread and submit a new `sqe`, like `openat2`.

I notice the `wait_cqe` doesn't return even the `openat2` is done(how I know it's done? I set `O_CREATE` and `ls` show the new file).

How to let a blocking `wait_cqe` knows there is a new submitted `sqe` and it's done, you need to return a `cqe` about it?

Comment: I don't think currently io_uring currently supports you doing submissions in that fashion (one ring shared by different threads) - https://github.com/axboe/liburing/issues/109 . The current model seems to push you to "a ring per thread"...

Comment: (Also note the above question was also asked on https://github.com/axboe/liburing/issues/127 )